# Android: How can I disable touchability?

Tags: android, imagebutton, ontouchlistener

I'm using android 2.0. I have a view (just a sipmle linearlayout with an image as background), which contains 3 imagebuttons. When I touch any part of this view, my buttons are not touchable any more. As they are disabled! How can I disable the touchability of the background? I just want to be able to touch the buttons even if I put my finger on the other parts of the view. Is that possible? 
The code sample:

```
public class myView extends LinearView {
public myView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public setView(Context context) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(backImg);    
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    setScrollContainer(false);

    ImageButton imgBtn0 = new ImageButton(context);
    imgBtn0.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imgBtn0.setBackgroundDrawable(imgBtnD0);
    imgBtn0.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imgBtn0.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener(context, id0));

    ...

    addView(imgBtn0, 0);
    addView(imgBtn1, 1);
    addView(imgBtn2, 2);

}

}
```

Comment: the behavior you are wanting should be the default. Can you post your layout xml file for us to see?

Comment: I have everything programatically and actually no xml-layouts.

Comment: can you post the java code you are using to make the layout then?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the touch of the linearlayout using `android:clicable="false"` but how will you figure out which image button to be clicked if the user clicks in the background?

Comment: I've tried the following for the root view without any success:
  setTouchDelegate(null);
  setClickable(false);
  setFocusable(false);
  setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
  setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
  setLongClickable(false);
  setClickable(false);
  setPressed(false);
  setSelected(false);
  setClickable(false);
  setFocusable(false);
  setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
  setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
  setLongClickable(false);
  setClickable(false);
  setPressed(false);
  setSelected(false);

Comment: you did not give me answer for "how will you figure out which image button to be clicked if the user clicks in the background?"

Comment: I give the id of my imagebutton to the touchlistener, but it's not my problem. The problem is: when I touch the background nothing else works!